# Log install and compilation

Tags: logging, installation, fedora, rpm, fedora-33

I m trying to install a product under fedora 33 in my VM, that it's manage the backup. But installation failed.

I have just this error message :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Lwn.png)

Where can i found more logs to help me install correctly the product, please ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
I also recommend reading [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Check the scriptlet using one of these:

```
rpm -q --scripts livenavigator
rpm -qp --scripts livenavigator*.rpm
```

And then try to find out which of the lines of the scripts cause the error.